# A line of Python and SQLite code, why I need to put ","?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(?)", (random.randint(0,100),))
```

If I change the above code, to:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(?)", (random.randint(0,100)))
```

I will get `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`.

I don't understand why I need the put a `,`? What's the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: (because you are using a single element in a tuple)

Comment: Without the comma, the second argument is not a tuple. It is the *comma* that makes it a tuple, not the parentheses (although they are needed here to remove the ambiguity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just basic Python syntax. The second value that `c.execute()` takes in is a tuple whose syntax requires trailing comma `,` when you put in just one variable to it.