# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I got the following error:

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/test/test_stats.py", line 43, in get_test_ids_for_id
    cursor.execute("""select test_id from test_logs where id = %s """, (id))
  File "/home/ec2-user/.etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here's the section of my code I'm having trouble with:

```
def get_test_ids_for_id(prod_mysql_conn, id):
    cursor = prod_mysql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select test_id from test_logs where id = %s """, (id))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    test_ids = []
    for row in rows:
      test_ids.append(row[0])
    return test_ids
```

Comment: That should be `cursor.execute(..., (id,))` - note the trailing comma, which makes it a tuple.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you explain clearly?

Comment: Martijn already has! See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22460082/3001761

Comment: hello try like this [id]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to give `cursor.execute` a tuple, but you only gave it one integer:

```
(id)
```

Add a comma to make that a tuple:

```
(id,)
```

The full line then'd be:

```
cursor.execute("""select test_id from test_logs where id = %s """, (id,))
```

Putting an expressione in parentheses just 'groups' that one expression. It is the *comma* that makes something a tuple:

```
>>> (42)
42
>>> (42,)
(42,)
```

Any iterable will do really, so you could also use `[...]` brackets:

```
cursor.execute("""select test_id from test_logs where id = %s """, [id])
```

Comment: Very annoying dealing with this

Comment: @briankip: why is it annoying? It's basic syntax; programming languages have always used the same symbols for different meanings in different contexts. Commas are used in tuples and when separating different parameters to a function signature, or for separating base classes in a class definition, or for separating the arguments in a call expression, or the values in a list, etc. Because you sometimes need to distinguish between a tuple and the other meanings, you need to use parentheses around the tuple to disambiguate it. But it is still the comma that makes something a tuple.

Comment: My main issue is that it's not intuitive that `cursor.execute` expects a tuple, especially for someone not steeped in the intricacies of MySQLdb. I expect for single parameters, there should be no need for the comma.

Comment: @briankip: so how would you distinguish between a single string parameter and multiple parameters? Take into account that a string is an iterable; it has `len(string)` elements.

Comment: @briankip: and this is not MySQLdb specific. It is common among all Python database adapters; they all follow the [Python Database API Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

Comment: I don't know really, I kind of expect it to work like a normal function with parameters.  You don't add a comma

Comment: @briankip: it works like a normal function with parameters. The second argument to the `cursor.execute()` function is the query parameters argument. It is a single object holding all values for the parameters. If you have just one parameter, then yes, that's a single-element tuple. For 2 or more, you get the 2 or more values in that one object. It can be a tuple or a list.

Comment: @briankip: if you use *named* parameters, then you use a mapping (dictionary), with parameter names as the keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147250/discussion-between-briankip-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is when you are passing a argument in query it is not becoming an iterable because it is coming in bracket. 
In order to make it iterable you need to make it in that form like list or tuple. Soo you can either add comma at the end (1,) or make it a list [1].